# the best method for google indexing text content in images?

Tags: seo, search-engine-bots

I have a webpage where I put 1 image once in a while, this is just like xkcd.com
I would like to know how to let google know the text in my images.

My approach is to put the text in alt html attribute, like this:

```
<img 
src="http://myapokalips.com/public/cartoons/021_Robot_Tattoo.png"
alt="RETARD - aw, that's a sick tattoo! - yea, bro, it means 'strength'" 
/>
```

is that right? or should I put the text in some random metatag?

Comment: Looks good to me. Keep in mind that not all browsers show the alt-attribute when hovering over the image. If you want it seen, you might want to use "title" as well.

Comment: did you find any solution on this matter? Is it possible to force google to index images with text?

Comment: @Lipis I'm sorry I don't know anything about google indexing images in text, I think they already does, but as in my case is handwrite-text my approach is to write it out by myself. till I find a good OCR in python.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like xkcd.com is doing.

Comment: xkcd does not. if you try searching some text wich is in the images you'll probably fail.